# How to disable xsrf validation on sap web ide?

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I am able to properly setup sap web ide on my local but after login I keep getting xsrf error on the browser.

I want to disable it in my local for local development and was not able to find any solution on internet.

I tried to find it on documentation and stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the file  `/Applications/SAPWebIDE/eclipse/orion.app/Contents/MacOS/orion.ini` with

```
-Dorion.XSRFPreventionFilterEnabled=false
```